# More elegant and efficient wayt to get the same output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df:

```
               info
{"any_name":{"value":["5"], "ref":"any text"}, "another_name":{"value":["2"], "ref":"any text"}
  {"any_name":{"value":["1"], "ref":"any text"}, "another_name":{"value":["12"], "ref":"any text"}
```

the dtype of this column is:

```
df['info'].apply(type) =>   <class 'str'>
```

I want to make a dataframe to get this output:

```
any_name  another_any_name
    5          2
    1          12
```

My solution is:

```
A=list(df['answers'])

J=[]
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    D=eval(A[i])
    foo = {k: v['value'] for k, v in D.items() if k in list_to_filter_columns}
    J.append(foo)
out=pd.DataFrame(J)
```

code to cast to numeric the values from `value` as they are list with one element

```
outt = outt.apply(lambda x: x.str[0])
outt = outt.apply(pd.to_numeric)
outt.head(2)
```

The above solution is working just fine.

I want to know if there's a more elegant way to get the same result. I think code above is very inefficient and not elegant.  Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop, you could use [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) :

```
import ast

df["info"] = df["info"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x+"}"))
​
out = (
        pd.json_normalize(df["info"])
                            .filter(regex="value$")
                            .astype(str)
                            .apply(lambda x: x.str.strip("['']"))
        )
​
out.columns = out.columns.str.replace("\.value", "", regex=True)
```

##### # Output

```
​
print(out)
  any_name another_name
0        5            2
1        1           12
```